# Use include tag in a given row/column of gridlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-gridlayout

I'm building a layout that should show full year calendar with months and days. I've already built the layout that represents month and days but now I'm unable to insert it into gridlayout at given x/y position since IDE shows `Exception raised during rendering: <include /> can only be used inside of a ViewGroup (Details)`

Basically, what i want to achieve is this:

[image]

Here are my files

#### calendar_month.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_month_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="MONTH" />

    <!-- days header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SUN"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="MON"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TUE"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="WED"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="THU"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="FRI"
            android:textColor="#222222" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="SAT"
            android:textColor="#222222" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- days view -->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="7" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### calendar_year.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/calendar_month_1"
                layout="@layout/calendar_month_view" />
        </View>
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the `View` for `FrameLayout` or some other view descended from `ViewGroup` as follows:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/calendar_month_1"
        layout="@layout/calendar_month_view" />
</FrameLayout>
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html).